# Sandbox access token not working [Easyship]

Tags: httprequest, sandbox, shipping-method

We have to try to integrate Easyship courier API. And We are facing the below issue.

```
{
    "rates": [],
    "messages": [
        "Sorry, we couldn't find any shipping solutions based on the information provided."
    ]
}
```

For more information, I have shared the request parameter and API response.

API URL:- https://api.easyship.com/v2/rates

Request Parameter:

```
{
  "origin_address": {
    "postal_code": "91601",
    "city": "Los Ángeles",
    "state": "CA",
    "country_alpha2": "US"
  },
  "destination_address": {
    "postal_code": "95140",
    "city": "Mount Hamilton",
    "state": "CA",
    "country_alpha2": "US"
  },
  "parcels": [
    {
      "total_actual_weight": 5,
      "items": [
        {
          "quantity": 1,
          "category": "mobile_phones",
          "dimensions": {
            "width": 10,
            "height": 10,
            "length": 25
          },
          "description": "Apple iPad",
          "actual_weight": 5,
          "declared_currency": "USD",
          "declared_customs_value": 49500.55
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Response Parameter:

```
{
  "status": "failure",
  "errors": [
    "Sorry, we couldn't find any shipping solutions based on the information provided."
  ],
  "request_id": "545b5f76a41e2994a13f384559dee625",
  "timestamp": "2022-10-12T10:09:21.272Z"
}
```

Note:

- This request parameter works with the **production access token**.
- We have applied all possible solutions for this issue but didn't find anything.
- **Also we don't want to use the production access token because we are in the developing stage. so please please provide working with a sandbox solution.**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the right token and check the body structure. The following sample works for me:

```
{
  "origin_address": {
    "line_1": "Kennedy Town",
    "line_2": "Block 3",
    "state": "Yuen Long",
    "city": "Hong Kong",
    "postal_code": "0000",
    "country_alpha2": "HK",
    "contact_name": "Foo Bar",
    "company_name": null,
    "contact_phone": null,
    "contact_email": "asd@asd.com"
  },
  "destination_address": {
    "country_alpha2": "HK",
    "line_1": "Kennedy Town",
    "line_2": "Block 3",
    "state": "Yuen Long",
    "city": "Hong Kong",
    "postal_code": "0000",
    "contact_name": "Foo Bar",
    "company_name": null,
    "contact_phone": null,
    "contact_email": "asd@asd.com"
  },
  "incoterms": "DDU",
  "insurance": {
    "is_insured": false
  },
  "courier_selection": {
    "show_courier_logo_url": false,
    "apply_shipping_rules": true
  },
  "shipping_settings": {
    "units": {
      "weight": "kg",
      "dimensions": "cm"
    }
  },
  "parcels": [
    {
      "box": null,
      "items": [
        {
          "quantity": 2,
          "dimensions": {
            "length": 1,
            "width": 2,
            "height": 3
          },
          "description": "item",
          "category": "fashion",
          "sku": "sku",
          "origin_country_alpha2": "HK",
          "actual_weight": 10,
          "declared_currency": "USD",
          "declared_customs_value": 20
        }
      ],
      "total_actual_weight": 1
    }
  ]
}
```